# Android NullPointerException setAdapter ViewPager

Tags: android

What wrong in my code? I was trying many times and examples, but error stay here. Can anybody help me? I searched the web and stackoverflow but found nothing about my problem.

This is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_IMAGE, (int) position);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

**DetailActivity.java**

```
public class DetailActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_IMAGE = "extra_image";

    CustomPagerAdapter mCustomPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    int index;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        index = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE, 0);

        mCustomPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(DetailActivity.this, MainActivity.mFilePath, index);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_detail, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        Context mContext;
        LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
        int index;
        Vector<String> images;

        public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context, Vector<String> images, int index) {
            this.mContext = context;
            this.images = images;
            this.index = index;
            mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return MainActivity.mFilePath.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.page_adapter, container, false);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_full);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(MainActivity.mFilePath.elementAt(position)));
            container.addView(itemView);

            return itemView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
        }
    }
}
```

**page_adapter.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/image_full"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**pager.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

And this is the error:

```
06-22 16:28:45.853    5995-5995/ua.zp.eldorado.testapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ua.zp.eldorado.testapp/ua.zp.eldorado.testapp.DetailActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2366)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1343)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5330)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at ua.zp.eldorado.testapp.DetailActivity.onCreate(DetailActivity.java:40)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5135)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2273)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2366)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1343)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5330)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: the pager is in the wrong layout, or at least it looks like accordingly to what you posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is in you layout was not correct then `mViewPager` variable is null and `exception` occurs by

```
mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);
```

try to replace

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
```

by

```
setContentView(R.layout.pager);
```

with `activity_detail.xml` `AndroidOS` can not find the element with id is `pager` then `mViewPager` is get value as `null`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your NPE is caused by this line

```
index = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE, 0);
```

Try Replacing it with

```
Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getExtras().get("EXTRA_IMAGE").ToString());
```